# Find intersection points of two ListPlot's in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have two sets of discrete data that I plot as two distinct colors(red and blue) with ListPlot in Mathematica. I want to find the intersection points(of the corresponding continuous curves) between those two, i.e. point A and B as shown.

[image]

I have tried 'FindCluster' method and hopping to get subsets of data forming lines but that does not work very well.

Now I always use 'GetCoordinate' property to get the numbers from the graph directly. It would be nice to have a way to do it automatically and more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will be convenient in your case, but I've sometimes let Mathematica interpolate lists of points and then solved for the intersection:

```
   findGuesses[pointsTable1_, pointsTable2_] := 
     Block[{interpolatingPolyF1, interpolatingPolyF2},
      interpolatingPolyF1 = 
       Function[{x}, Evaluate[InterpolatingPolynomial[pointsTable1, x]]];
      interpolatingPolyF2 = 
       Function[{x}, Evaluate[InterpolatingPolynomial[pointsTable2, x]]];
      (*Print[Plot[{interpolatingPolyF1[x],interpolatingPolyF2[x]},{x,0,2}]];*)
      {x, y} /. 
       NSolve[{y == interpolatingPolyF1[x], 
         y == interpolatingPolyF2[x]}, {x, y}, Reals]
      ]
```

Comment: This does not work in my case since it is impossible to interpolate the data I have(they are multivalue functions as seen from the figure). The solution you provided works for single value functions only I suppose. Thank you anyway.